# Linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^7$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation on $T : \mathbb{R}^7 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^7$ defined by $$ T(x_1,x_2,...,x_7)=(x_7,x_6,...,x_1)$$ Then which of the following are true ?

> 1) $det(T)=1$
>
> 2) $\exists$ a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^7$ such that $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ is diagonal
>
> 3) $T^7=I$
>
> 4) the smallest $n$ such that $T^n=I$ is even.

Mt attempt:

A simple calculation shows $T^2=I$,  so 4) is true and 3) is false

For 1):  In general, the determinant of $T= (-1)^{\text{dim V}}.(\text{constant term of the characteristic polynomial of T) }$

So, we must find the matrix of $T$ in any basis and hence we find the determinant of that matrix, which is same as $det(T)$

My Question is:

**Is there any short cut way to find the determinant of T ?**

**How to approach 2) ?**

I'm  find the matrix of $T$ w.t.to the standard basis. But that matrix is not diagonal.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that $T$ is self-adjoint (just look at its matrix under the standard basis), and hence diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes three transpositions of the seven standard unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^7$ to create $T$: $\vec{e}_1\leftrightarrow\vec{e}_7$, $\vec{e}_2\leftrightarrow\vec{e}_6$, $\vec{e}_3\leftrightarrow\vec{e}_5$. So $T$ is an odd permutation of the seven standard unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^7$. So it's determinant is $(-1)^3=-1$.

$T$'s matrix with respect to the standard basis is antidiagonal with all $1$s. So $T$'s standard matrix is a symmetric matrix. So $T$ is (orthogonally) diagonalizable. That makes item 2) true.

In fact, it's easy to see what the basis $\mathcal{B}$ could be. It's clear that $\vec{v}_4$ is one eigenvector of eignevalue $1$. So are $\vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_7$, $\vec{v}_2+\vec{v}_6$, and $\vec{v}_3+\vec{v}_5$. And some eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$ are $\vec{v}_1-\vec{v}_7$, $\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_6$, and $\vec{v}_3-\vec{v}_5$. These are seven linearly independent eignevectors.

Comment: Ok..fine. T is diagonalizable implies there exist an invertible $H$ such that $HTH^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix. From this, how exactly 2) follows ?  (sorry, i don't understand)

Comment: To be diagonalizable _really_ means what 2) asks for. It is equivalent to the algebraic meaning of diagonalizability you just wrote. The columns of your $H^{-1}$ are the basis vectors in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: In other words, if $D=HTH^{-1}$, and $\mathcal{B}=\{H^{-1}_1,\ldots,H^{-1}_7\}$ (the columns of $H^{-1}$), then $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ _is_ $D$.

Comment: Oh!  Since $detT=-1 \neq 0$, so $T$ is invertible and hence any $7$ linearly independent vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^7$, so 2) is true

Comment: Very Clear explanation! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, you don't need $T$ to be invertible for "any 7 linearly independent vectors form a basis". That is always true in $\mathbb{R}^7$. And also I don't see what that has to do with $T$ being diagonalizable. Unless the 7 vectors are eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: ok! I understand

Comment: can you recommend any good book on linear algebra?

Comment: An expensive one is Lay. It's what we use. A good free one is [Beezer](http://linear.ups.edu/fcla/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The given linear transformation takes the basis (in the given order) and reverses the order.  The *reversal permutation* of any number of items is achieved by exchanging the extreme elements, then again exchanging the extremes in the remaining elements and so on. (if odd number of elements, the middle one left alone will be fixed).

Now look at the alternative basis: $e_1+e_7, e_1-e_7, e_2+e_6, e_2-e_6, e_3+e_5, e_3-e_5, e_4$. Easy to verify that they generate all the $e_i$'s and are in the right number hence a basis.

We can check that $T$'s effect on this new basis: they are fixed or sent to their negatives. These are the eigenvectors forming a basis, providing diagonalization. SO determinant is computed immediately.

Comment: This one helps too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the permutation matrix corresponding to the permutation $\rho$
then $\det A$ is the sign of $\rho$.

If $T^2=I$, what does that tell you about the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: $1$ and $-1$ are the eigenvalues of T. Am i right?